# Solve coupled nonlinear differential equation - truck towing car problem

Tags: derivatives, nonlinear-dynamics

Imagine a truck towing a car using a taught rope of constant length $l$. The trucks position at any time is $(x,y)$ and is known in parametric form:

$$x=f(t)$$
$$y=g(t)$$

The position of the car $(X,Y)$ is thus described by:
$$X = x - l \cos\theta$$
$$Y = y - l \sin\theta$$

Since the car is forced to point towards the truck at all times, the following constraint applies:
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{\dot{Y}}{\dot{X}}$$

It should be possible to use this information to solve for the motion of the car assuming generic initial conditions. By use of algebra I get the following nonlinear coupled differential equation:

$$X = f(t) - \frac{l\dot{X}}{\sqrt{\dot{X}^2+\dot{Y}^2}}$$
$$Y = g(t) - \frac{l\dot{Y}}{\sqrt{\dot{X}^2+\dot{Y}^2}}$$

Can someone solve this? Perhaps by using a clever change of variables?

Comment: It's unlikely that you could solve this in anything like closed form for arbitrary $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to write an equation for $\theta$.  With $X = f(t) - l \cos(\theta)$ and $Y = g(t) - l \sin(\theta)$, I get
$$ \dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \dfrac{\sin(\theta) \dot{g}(t) - \cos(\theta) \dot{f}(t)}{l} $$
This will have closed-form solutions for some $\dot{f}$ and $\dot{g}$, but not arbitrary ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree it'll be easier to solve for $\theta$ using this NL differential equation and then substitute it into equations for $X$ and $Y$. I believe you made a minor mistake in the algebra. I believe the correct equation is:

$$ \dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \dfrac{\cos(\theta) \dot{g}(t) - \sin(\theta) \dot{f}(t)}{l} $$